# So my root file system is filled to the brim due to log files

Tags: 20.04, disk-usage, storage

So I have fairly recently started using Ubuntu as my main OS and it has been quite smooth for the past 4 months but today I was intimated that the system is full and on checking the var/log/ seems to have used an enormous chunk from my hard drive and I really don't know what to do and need advice.
Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: I have read a few other answers but they weren't really helpful.

Comment: First think to think about, is to check why, if it is only due to "normal" logging, you have to adjust your logrotate & set it up to compress older logs. If it is due to a fault in some application, you have to fix that (I think it that seeing size of your log directory) & remove older logs.

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 is long out of service, who knows what security issues might be present, logging all sorts of bad things.  You need to backup your files, and reinstall a more current release, 20.04, or 21.10.

Comment: Oh my bad it's 20.04 (typo)

Comment: Find the logs that are eating up your space. You indicate syslog and syslog.1. Take a look at syslog and look for a repeating error. That's what you have to fix. Delete the syslog.1 file, and any of the compressed syslog files, if space is getting real critical.

Answer (score 0):

use `stacer`
install it with `sudo apt install stacer`,
next open stacer and folle the picures [image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

click the blue button type in your password and your done.

Comment: Are you sure that nothing will happen if i delete those log files ?

Comment: And syslog and syslog1 are the primary space eater's

Comment: only do logs if you like

Comment: Don't do this until you've looked at what's in the logs.

Comment: Do not remove logs until you fix the reason logs are so big !   /var/log may never increase over 8Gb even on small production servers,  so having much log space, is of course a very big issue symptom.  Cure the issue, not the symptom !  Only AFTER doing that you can purge/sort the useless logs

Comment: syslog consumed 500GiB and syslog.1 consumed 250GiB so i followed another thread to empty the log files then restarted their service